# Trying to ...".pack_forget()" all items from a looped list

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code inside my method:

```
class Graphics:
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.geometry("640x640")    
        root.title("Hello")
        root.configure(bg = "black")

        self.scoreButton = Button(root, text = "See Score", command = self.score)
        self.HomeButton = Button(root, text = "Menu", command = self.deleteScore)

     def score(self):
         for i,e in enumerate(self.myList, start=1):                                               
             if e == "10":
                 self.seeScore = Label(text = "Times played: " + str(i) + " - Loss", bg="black", fg="white", font = ("Arial", 15))
                 self.seeScore.pack()
             else:                                           
                 self.seeScore = Label(text = "Times played " + str(i) + "Score: " + str(e), bg="black", fg="white", font = ("Arial", 15))
                 self.seeScore.pack()

     def deleteScore(self):
         self.seeScore.pack_forget()
```

As of right now it only forgets the last item when i run the method but i want it to forget all the items... I cant figure out how to do this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please, share your full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete or hide a list of widgets, you have to actually store the widgets in a list.

### Example

```
self.labels = []
for i,e in enumerate(self.myList, start=1):                                               
    if e == "10":
        label = Label(text = str(i), bg="black", fg="white", font = ("Arial", 15))
        self.HelloWorld.pack()
    else:                                           
        label = Label(text = str(i) + str(e), bg="black", fg="white", font = ("Arial", 15))
        self.HellowWorld.pack()
    self.labels.append(label)
```

...

```
def deleteHelloWorld(self):
    for widget in self.labels:
        widget.pack_forget()
```